# How to inheritate 2 db model classes from same parent and make it work in hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

So in database I have 2 table where some columns have the same name/type.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int age;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class B {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
}
```

I want to have a parent class that has the `name` field, so I don't have to create it in the class `A` and class `B`. This also helps me when I have to iterate through the records because now in my program I have 2 functions that are 99% the same. Only difference that function for class `A` use a for cycle like this: `for (A a : aList) { a.getname(); }` when the other `for (B b : bList) { b.getName(); }`. I want to turn this 2 functions into one what looks like this: `for (C c : list) { c.getName(); }`.

Also the classes how they look like now:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A extends C {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private int age;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class B extends C {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String email;
}

@Data
public class C {
   private String name;
}
```

I can not change the DB. I can modify only my java classes. So for example I can't put them in one table. The 2 child classes have their own ID and they come from different tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found out all I had to do to add `@MappedSuperClass` to class `C`.

So it looks like this:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class C {
   private String name;
}
```

and works great.